# Mule Rabbit MQ JMS connector reconnection on network failure

Tags: jms, rabbitmq, mule

I have a mule application and its utilising JMS connectors. I added the  tag however the issue is not yet fixed. Whenever the network connection is broken and comes up again the MULE app is unable to connect to JMS MQ. please advice.

Code is below Please advise.

`<jms:connector name="JMS" specification="1.1"
        validateConnections="true" jndiInitialFactory="com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory"
        jndiProviderUrl="file:bindings" connectionFactoryJndiName="ConnectionFactory" 
        doc:name="JMS"/>`

Comment: Did you tried with JMS connector, reconnect option like this  <jms:connector name="JMS" validateConnections="true" doc:name="JMS"><reconnect  frequency="2000" count="5"/>
    </jms:connector>. Could you please let me know why you have choosen JMS over AMQP?. Any specific advantages?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried this approach which is mentioned in other threads as well . But still the same issue persists.  <logs>com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: clean connection shutdown; reason: Attempt to use closed connection
 at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.ensureIsOpen(AMQConnection.java:168)
 at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.createChannel(AMQConnection.java:488)
 at com.rabbitmq.jms.client.RMQConnection.createRabbitChannel(RMQConnection.java:280)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)</logs>

Comment: We are using ETL for persisting data in DB and its unable to read data from the queue using AMQP effectively hence JMS is being used. ETL tool has the ability to read the messages from queue efficiently using JMS. Here request from application is posted via JMS to ETL.  ETL will post the response over AMQP to the application.

Comment: Already closedException Clearly says.Request  is already closed. You are trying to use same again and again but it was already acknowledged. If you done dubug point and notice, it will clearly show you.

Answer (score 0):

I have also got this exception when I retry the scenario.Ex: If the service is down( Network failure) in-between the flow, it will initiate retry from the queue again and again, it might initiate 3 retires(same payload). If the service is up, whichever the payload comes first, it will acknowledge( success). For remaining 2 payload it will throw this exception .I'm sure if you debug,see inbound Property , check `delivery-tag`. It would have acknowledged on separate thread.In this case, capture exception, make `reject message`( Since I used amqp- You can handle based on you exception handler needs), but it all happen on your requirement and you can also handle in other possible way  what your requirement is.

Not sure you have used retry scenario, but all it  falls under the same category in other means.Acknowledge is problem, check this properly.